# How to show/hide a window in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to show or hide a window on MacOS when a key combination is pressed.

I'm starting with activation `accessory` and I've got a handler registered in the AppDelegate that activates the window:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)
        hotkey = ....
        hotkey?.keyDownHandler = {
            NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        }
```

So far so good, that works. Now I'd like to make sure the window disappears when the key is released:

```
@main
struct FooApp: App {
    ...
    var body: some Scene {
        Window("FooWindow", id: "switcher") {....}
        .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { newScenePhase in
            if newScenePhase == .active {
                hotkey?.keyUpHandler = {
                    window?.close()
                }
            }
        })
```

Where `window` is the `NSWindow` corresponding to that window.

This works - once. When I press the key combination, the window appears, when I release it closes. But it doesn't appear anymore afterwards.

What should I do instead? Should I be opening it, or closing it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API to hide (rather than to close) a window is [`orderOut(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419660-orderout)

And the API to show a window and move it to the front is [`orderFront(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419495-orderfront)